# working with createDocumentFragment() without ids

Tags: javascript, documentfragment

I'm trying to build the following using `createDocumentFragment()` and append it to `document.body`. My usual approach would be to reference an element by it's `id`. Since there are no `'id`s here, how do I build something like this?

```
<div class="Mh0NNb VcC8Fc" style="visibility:visible;">
    <div class="M6tHv">
        <div class="aGJE1b">Success</div>
        <div class="dnmu6e"></div>
        <div class="x95qze">Close</div>
        <div class="dnmu6e"></div>
    </div>
</div>

frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

n = document.createElement('div')
n.setAttribute('class','Mh0NNb VcC8Fc')
frag.appendChild(n)

n = document.createElement('div')
n.setAttribute('class','M6tHv')
a = frag.getElementsByClassName('Mh0NNb') // This seems to not work
frag.appendChild(a)
```

Comment: Reference the first item in the class collection?

Comment: @CertainPerformance But it seems `getElementsByClassName` wont work on fragment...

Comment: Oh, you're right, forgot that quirk. You'll have to use `querySelector` instead, eg `querySelector('.Mh0NNb')`